# GCC/Clang 'labels as values' computing offsets at runtime

Tags: c, gcc, clang, goto

I am using [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) (nonstandard extension) to jump to goto labels.

Below is a state machine implementation, simplified for brevity, where states are coded as offsets of the corresponding labels.

```
// Processes char c and returns next state
// cur_state = 0 for initial state
int sm_process_char( int cur_state, char c, void *data )
{
    goto *(&&Init + cur_state);
    Init:

    State0:
    switch ( c )
    {
        case 'A': return (&&State_A - &&Init);
        default: return (&&State_Error - &&Init);
    }

    State_A:
    switch ( c )
    {
        case 'A': return (&&State_A - &&Init);
        case 'B': return (&&State_B - &&Init);
        default: return (&&State_Error - &&Init);
    }

    State_B:
    switch ( c )
    {
        case 'A': return (&&State_A - &&Init);
        case 'B': return (&&State_B - &&Init);
        default: return (&&State_Error - &&Init);
    }

    State_Error:
    return cur_state;
}
```

The assembly generated by this code is far from optimal with `-O3`:

```
sm_process_char:
        movsx   rax, edi
        add     rax, OFFSET FLAT:.L2
        jmp     rax
.L5:
.L9:
        cmp     sil, 65
        je      .L8
        cmp     sil, 66
        je      .L10
.L4:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.L7
        sub     rdi, OFFSET FLAT:.L2
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
.L7:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
.L2:
        cmp     sil, 65
        jne     .L4
.L8:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.L5
        sub     rdi, OFFSET FLAT:.L2
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
.L10:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.L9
        sub     rdi, OFFSET FLAT:.L2
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

Notice the `mov` and `sub` instructions computing the difference in offsets. I was expecting that these could be done in compile time and be replaced with singe `mov` instructions.

Is it possible to make GCC/Clang compute these in compile time and end up with a better assembly?

Godbolt link here: https://godbolt.org/z/zZdFYo

Comment: Do you have a good reason to avoid using a `switch` with some `enum` for the state instead of `goto`?

Comment: Usually you'd have an array of label addresses, and `goto jumptable[index];` instead of what you're doing... (Or store the addresses in a bytecode setup and jump to the next one directly)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Look up 'threaded code'.

Comment: @Shawn I looked that up. Still don't see a reason.  `switch` is just a fancy `goto`. It will keep the same code structure, and any sane compiler will produce the same or better code. Basically a `switch` compiles to a jump table.

Comment: the use of a `switch()` and a `case` for each `state` is the easy way to do this.  Why make it difficult on your self?

Comment: is this `c` or `c++`?  They are different languages.  Please Pick one and remove the `tag` for the other language

Comment: The missed optimization might have something to do with the complication that applying it changes the answer.  (It surely converges after just one or two iterations, but it’s hard to phrase it as a sequence of correct transformations.)

Comment: Regardless of particular use-case this might be a good suggestion to GCC developers so I encourage you to [file a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) or send mail to gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org.